# Snowflake: Converting a date + timestamp to timestamp + day of the week

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Right now, I have a column which is in date + timestamp format. Like so:
2022-02-24 17:30:00.000

Does anyone know how to convert this into something like Thursday 17:30:00.000

I don't want to convert anything to a string and concat that way, as then it'll be difficult to graph in snowsight.

Comment: `I don't want to convert anything to a string and concat that way, as then it'll be difficult to graph in snowsight.` what does this mean?? if you have the output of a TO_CHAR that works, but gives `Thursday 17:30:00.000` how is the SQL that gets the string answer more hard for Snowsight??

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim OP is probably referring to charts in Snowsight where, if you have a proper date field, you can use different time bucket for aggregation; kind of like slicers in excel. Honestly though,  I am surprised someone uses  Snowsight for visualization. I found it way too limiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake has a 3 Letter Day, but does not appear to have full name days, for free in the [TO_CHAR formatting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#about-the-format-specifiers-in-this-section).

```
SELECT '2022-02-24 17:30:00.000'::timestamp as my_timestamp,
    TO_CHAR(my_timestamp, 'DY HH:MM:SS.FF');
```

| MY_TIMESTAMP | TO_CHAR(MY_TIMESTAMP, 'DY HH:MM:SS.FF') |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-24 17:30:00.000 | Thu 17:02:00.000000000 |

but that is not the long form you requested.